# Package.json complicated start script with "sh -ac" and .env file for Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

In [Firefly example project](https://github.com/sampl/firefly)   in `package.json` there is

```
"start": "sh -ac '. ./.env.dev; firebase use dev &&  react-scripts start'",
```

On my Windows 10 its not working with `&&`:

> Now using alias dev (firefly-boilerplate) 
>   Unknown script "start'". 
>   react-scripts start'

This script works with `;` instead of `&&` , App starts, but  it doesn't connect fo database:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.0.4): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 2 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: The project firefly-boilerplate
 does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore database.
```

So I must put Api key, domain, and project name from `.env.dev` into `index.js` to work. Why this script doesn't work with `&&`?

What `sh -ac` command exacly do?

Answer (score 11):

`sh` is the POSIX command for running a shell (a shell is the program that powers the command-line terminal). Running `sh -ac` is saying "run the shell command and automatically export all variables assigned during its run" effectively.

A `.env` file is often used to describe local environment variables needed for scripts to run, so `sh -ac ./.env.dev` is basically saying **load all the environment variables from `.env.dev`**.

Those environment variables are then made available in the subsequent commands via `&&` which executes multiple commands in a single context.

This script is, simply speaking, not very Windows-friendly. What you would want to do is take a look inside `.env.dev` at the environment variables it's setting and then set those in your local terminal before running the `firebase` and `react-scripts` commands.

Comment: strange enough that without "./" it wouldn't work (I am using WSL) E.g. it has to be
"start": "sh -ac '. ./.env.dev; ... instead of "start": "sh -ac '. .env.dev; ... otherwise it complains file not found